# llamar una funcion de Python desde javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, json, xml

Tengo un javascript que debe ejecutar una funcion de python y obtener la respuesta. En este caso no necesito enviar datos eventualmente voy a tener que pasar datos en formato de json o xml

```
test.py
import hug

@hug.get()
def hola_apis():
  return "Hola Mundo"

//test.js
$("#btnBuscar").click(aj);    
function aj() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: "test.py",
        success: function(response){
           output = response;
           alert(response);
        }
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    alert(data);
});
};
```

Comment: Con ajax realizas peticiones http, estas usando solo python o usas un framework (django, flask, ...)

Comment: En verdad no estoy usando nada.
Mi idea era sencillamente ejecutar el script y recibir la respuesta del SOAP  (XML) en el response.
Por lo que vi tengo que generar el template y devolver lo que quiero que el JS ponga en el html

Comment: En django se hace la configuración de las url en un archivo llamado `urls.py` a estas son donde se apunta el llamado con ajax, no sabria como ejecutar este llamado directamente a python